# Java: Using 2 or more Classes for Freemarker Data Model processing

Tags: java, freemarker

I've got a problem with understanding the Freemarker Data Model and how to work with it correctly.
I currently have 1 Core Data Class.
It is stuffed as hell (a lot of variables with getters and setters) and I want to split it into different Classes.

But my Core Class is fueling a Freemarker processing... And I just don't get, how to get this working with several classes.

Currently I use this:

```
templateValues.process(config_generator.CDATA, stringWriter);
```

CDATA is my Core Data Class...
I checked the Freemarker guide several times, but I just don't get it.

If I would implement 2 Classes (CDATA1 & CDATA2 i.e.) how would I set up the processing? And would this work with even more Classes as well? (CDATA3 to X).

Answer (score 1):

I know i am too late but why not do something like

```java
Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
dataModel.put("CDATA1", config_generator.CDATA1);
dataModel.put("CDATA2", config_generator.CDATA2);
templateValues.process(dataModel, stringWriter);
```

Correct me if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature out of the box, but it's just the question of the `TemplateHashModel` implementation you pass in as the data model. (The data model is always a `TemplateHashModel`, though if you pass in a POJO FreeMarker will adapt it automatically via the `ObjectWrapper` in the `Configuration`.) You could easily write a `TemplateHashModel` implementation that encloses a list of other `TemplateHashModel`-s, and whose `get(String)` returns the requested variable from the first enclosed `TemplateHashModel` whose `get(String)` returns non-`null`. To adapt your POJO (`CDATA1` etc.) to `TemplateHashModel` call `cfg.getObjectWrapper().wrap(myObject)`, where `cfg` is the `freemarker.template.Configuration` object.

Comment: Wow...sorry... In fact I think I do not get you. Seems my "Java" is not nearly as good, as hoped. :)